# Is there a way to see that the map $\gamma:V\rightarrow \text{Cl}(V)$ is injective from construction?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ideals, quotient-spaces, clifford-algebras

Let $(V,Q)$ be a $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ linear vector space with a symmetric bilinear form $Q$. Then we can construct a Clifford algebra by taking the tensor algebra $T(V)$, and taking the quotient by the ideal $I$ generated by the subsets:

$$I=\{v\otimes v+Q(v,v):v\in V\}$$

Let $\gamma=\pi\circ i$, where $i:V\rightarrow T(V)$ is the inclusion map, and $\pi:T(V)\rightarrow T(V)/I$ is the quotient map. If one could show that $I\cap V=\{0\}$ it should then follow that the map $\gamma:V\rightarrow T(V)/I$ is injective. Let $v\in I\cap V$, then:

$$v=\sum_{i}a_i\otimes (v_i\otimes v_i+Q(v_i,v_i))\otimes b_i$$

Since $v\in V$ we can assume that for each $i$ the degree of $a_i$ and $b_i$ sum to $1$, i.e.
either $a_i$ is a vector, and $b_i$ is a scalar or vice versa. Since $v\in V$, we need:

$$\sum_ia_i\otimes (v_i\otimes v_i)\otimes b_i=0$$
My question is then, can we use this to show that:
$$\sum_{i}a_i\otimes b_i Q(v_i,v_i)=0$$
I don't see a way forward to prove this, and I suspect these conditions are a little to0 general to see why this should be immediately clear. I believe it should be true, since there are other ways to show that $\gamma$ is an injection.

One thought I had was to consider the map:

$$Q':V^{\otimes 4}\rightarrow V^{\otimes 2}$$

given on simple tensors by:

$$Q'v_1\otimes v_2\otimes v_3\otimes v_4\rightarrow v_1\otimes v_4 \dot Q(v_2,v_3)$$

but then I quickly remembered that one of $a_i$ or $b_i$ is a scalar, so I would really need a map from $V^{\otimes 3}\rightarrow V$, and since $a_i$ or $b_i$ could be a vector on either side of $v_i\otimes v_i$, I don't think there is a consistent way of obtaining a map like that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the answer by MTS to the MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68378/clifford-algebra-non-zero).

Comment: @KCd this is the other way of proving it I know. I was wondering if there was a way to get directly from the construction, by directly showing that $I\cap V=\{0\}$

Comment: Oh!  You should've given that background context in your question. To be honest, working with the ideal $I$ in a direct way seems like it would be a mess. Have you looked in books that develop Clifford algebras to see how they compute the dimension to be $2^n$? Jacobson's Basic Algebra II is one such book. Any proof of the dimension ought to include at least implicitly an argument that $V$ embeds into the Clifford algebra of $(V,Q)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand\gtensor{\mathbin{\hat\otimes}}
\newcommand\gen[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
$I'm having a surprisingly hard time finding this result (though one should really expect I'd find it if I keep looking). Pertti Lounesto references Bourbaki 1959 and T.Y. Lam 1973 in *Clifford Algebras and Spinors*, but I've not had success finding a copy of either. Ian Porteous goes a much different route in *Clifford Algebras and the Classical Groups* by constructing real/complex Clifford algebras as matrix algebras or direct sums of matrix algebras.

Larry Grove gives the following "proof" in *Classic Groups and Geometric Algebra* (which I paraphrase here):

> **Proposition 8.7.** The linear transformation $\pi$ restricted to $V$ is 1-1.
>
> **Proof.** Note that $\ker \pi|_V = V\cap I$. Since $V \subseteq T(V)$ has no elements of degree greater than 1, whereas $I$ is generated by elements of degree 2, it is clear that $V\cap I = 0$.

This doesn't make any sense to me, and indeed if this argument worked then it would work just as well if $V$ were a module over an arbitary ring; but Jacques Helmstetter and Artibano Micali give Example 3.1.3 on page 106 of *Quadratic Mappings and Clifford Algebra* as a counterexample.

So below I give my proof in terms of the ideal $I$, and then also a corresponding proof in terms of universal properties and the fundamental isomorphism $\Cl(V,Q) \cong \Cl(V_1,Q)\gtensor\Cl(V_2,Q)$ where $V = V_1\oplus V_2$ is an orthogonal decomposition.

## In Terms of $I$

We write $\Cl(V, Q) = T(V)/I$ and $Q(w) = Q(w,w)$.

The result is almost trivial when $Q$ is non-degenerate. Suppose there is nonzero $v$ such that $\pi(v) = 0$. For any $w \in V$ we have
$$
  2Q(v, w) = \pi(v + w)^2 - \pi(v)^2 - \pi(w)^2 = \pi(v)\pi(w) + \pi(w)\pi(v) = 0.
$$
Thus $v$ must be in the radical $V^\perp$, and so we have

**Lemma.** If $Q$ is non-degenerate then $\pi$ restricted to $V$ is injective. Equivalently, $V\cap I = \{0\}$.

---

**Note: the following argument is likely broken, see the comments. However, I believe the argument in terms of universal properties further down is sound.**

---

Now consider an orthogonal decomposition $V = V_1 \oplus V^\perp$; it follows that $V_1\cap I_1 = \{0\}$ where $I_1$ is the ideal of $T(V_1) \subseteq T(V)$ generated by elements of the form $v\otimes v - Q(v)$ for $v \in V_1$.

Every $w \in V$ can be uniquely written $w = u + r$ for $u \in V_1$ and $r \in V^\perp$. Thus if $v \in V\cap I$ we may write
$$
  v = \sum_ia_i\otimes X_i\otimes b_i
$$
where
$$
  X_i
    = w_i\otimes w_i - Q(w_i)
    = u_i\otimes u_i - Q(u_i) + r_i\otimes r_i + u_i\otimes r_i + r_i\otimes u_i
$$
with $u_i \in V_1$ and $r_i \in V^\perp$. We may assume that each term of the sum in $v$ has grade 1; WLOG we may assume $(a_i, b_i) = (v'_i, 1)$ for $v'_i \in V_1$ or $v'_i \in V^\perp$.

Let $X'_i = u_i\otimes u_i - Q(u_i)$. Since $v'_i\otimes X_i$ has grade 1 it follows that $w\otimes X_i$ has grade 1 for all $w \in  V$, in particular $w \in V_1$. But then $w\otimes X'_i$ is in $V_1\cap I_1$ and so must be zero:
$$
  0 = w\otimes X'_i = -Q(u_i)w.
$$
Whether or not $V_1$ is trivial we get $Q(u_i) = 0$. So now
$$
  X_i = u_i\otimes u_i + r_i\otimes r_i + u_i\otimes r_i + r_i\otimes u_i
$$
and every term of $v$ is of grade at least 2, hence $v = 0$.

## In Terms of Universal Properties

Essentially what I will do now is show that the subalgebra generated by $V^\perp$ is isomorphic to its exterior algebra while also preserving the map $\pi : V^\perp \to \Cl(V,Q)$. Then since the natural map $V \to \Ext V^\perp$ is injective we get that $\pi$ is injective on $V^\perp$. First we prove the all-important universal property.

**Theorem 1.** $\Cl(V,Q)$ satisfies the following universal propery: for any other associative algebra $A$ and linear $f : V \to A$ such that $f(w)^2 = Q(w)$ there is a unique algebra homomorphism $F : \Cl(V,Q) \to A$ such that $F(\pi(w)) = f(w)$ for all $w \in V$.

**Proof.** By the universal propery of $T(V)$ there is a unique algebra homomorphism $G : T(V) \to A$ such that $G(w) = f(w)$ for all $w \in V$. We write $\iota \in I$ as
$$
  \iota = \sum_ia_i\otimes(v_i\otimes v_i - Q(v_i))\otimes b_i
$$
whence
$$
  G(\iota) = \sum_iG(a_i)(f(v_i)^2 - Q(v_i))G(b_i) = 0.
$$
Thus $G$ descends to the desired homomorphism $F : \Cl(V,Q) \to A$. $\quad\Box$

**Definition.** The *$\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-graded tensor product* $A\gtensor B$ of two $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-graded algebras $A, B$ is a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-graded algebra defined with underlying set $A\otimes B$ and such that
$$
  (a\otimes b)(a'\otimes b') = (-1)^{\partial a'\partial b}(aa')\otimes(bb')
$$
where $b, a'$ are homogeneous with degrees $\partial b, \partial a'$.

**Theorem 2.** Let $V = V_1\oplus V_2$ be an orthogonal decomposition. Identify $T(V_1)$ and $T(V_2)$ as subalgebras of $T(V)$ and let $\pi_i$ denote the natural projection of $\Cl(V_i, Q)$. Then there is an algebra isomorphism
$$
  \psi : C = \Cl(V_1,Q)\gtensor\Cl(V_2, Q) \cong \Cl(V,Q)
$$
such that $\psi(\pi_1(w)) = \pi(w)$ for all $w \in V_1$ and $\psi(\pi_2(w)) = \pi(w)$ for $w \in V_2$.

**Corollary.** $\pi$ is injective on $V$ for any $Q$.

**Proof.** We choose $V_2 = V^\perp$ whence $\Cl(V_2, Q) = \Ext V^\perp$. If $\Ext V^\perp = T(V^\perp)/I_\perp$ with $I_\perp$ the appropriate ideal, then if $v \in V^\perp\cap I_\perp$ we see that $v = 0$ since every element of $I_\perp$ has degree at least 2. Hence $\pi_2$ is injective on $V^\perp$ and so $\pi = \psi\circ\pi_2$ is injective on $V^\perp$. Similarly $\pi_1$ is injective on $V_1$ by the Lemma and so $\pi$ is injective on $V_1$. Hence $\pi$ is injective on $V = V_1\oplus V_2$. $\quad\Box$

**Proof of Theorem 2.** For each $i = 1,2$, by the universal property of $\Cl(V_i, Q)$ we get a homomorphism $\psi_i : \Cl(V_i,Q) \to \Cl(V,Q)$ such that $\psi_i(\pi_i(w)) = \pi(w)$ for $w \in V_i$. Define $\psi = \psi_1\otimes\psi_2$. By the universal property of $\Cl(V,Q)$ we get $\phi : \Cl(V,Q) \to C$ such that
$$
  \phi(\pi(w_i)) = \pi_i(w_i)\quad\text{when }w_i \in V_i.
$$
If $X_1 \in T(V_1)$ and $X_2 \in T(V_2)$ it now easily follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
  \phi\Bigl(\psi(\pi_1(X_1)\otimes\pi_2(X_2))\Bigr)
    &= \phi\Bigl(\psi_1\bigl(\pi_1(X_1))\otimes\psi_2(\pi_2(X_2)\bigr)\Bigr)
\\
    &= \phi(\pi(X_1))\otimes\phi(\pi(X_2))
\\
    &= \pi_1(X_1)\otimes\pi_2(X_2).
\end{aligned}$$
Every element $C$ is a sum of elements of the form $\pi_1(X_1)\otimes\pi_2(X_2)$, so by linearity $\psi = \phi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism with the requisite properties. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thank you, this is very nice. I do wish there was a way to prove it without assuming $Q$ was non degenerate though.

Comment: @Chris I don't assume that. I prove it for the case $Q$ is non-degenerate (the Lemma) and then use that fact to prove it in the general case. Or are you saying you wish there were a way that didn't make this sort of case analysis?

Comment: Oh you are right, I got confused, my bad.

Comment: Wait why can we assume with out loss of generality that $(a_i,b_i)=(v'_i,1)$? We can't swap tensor product, so there could be terms like $(a_i,b_i)=(1,v'_i)$, no?

Comment: @Chris Maybe not the best choice of words. What I mean is the proof is almost exactly the same regardless of what side $v_i'$ is on.

Comment: I see, however, I can't see how we can assume each term in the sum of $v$ has grade one. I agree we can rewrite $v$ as a sum of grade one terms, but that get's rid of the grade two terms in $X_i$. In other words, I don't believe it is correct to say that $w\otimes  X_i$ is grade one for all $i$, because $X_i=w_i\otimes w_i-Q(w_i)$, so $w\otimes X_i$ is inhomogenous.

Comment: Actually, I believe your conclusion in the first part is incorrect. Particularly, if $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, and the orthogonal decomposition is $V=\mathbb{R}^t\oplus\mathbb{R}^s$, where $t+s=n$, and $Q$ is identically zero on $t$, but is the euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^t$, then we can't have $Q(u_i)=0$.

Comment: @Chris To your first point: I think you're right, what we can say is that the sum is zero or that each term has a grade 1 component. This probably breaks the argument, I will add a disclaimer. To your second point: we absolutely can have $Q(u_i) = 0$, it just means that $u_i = 0$.

Comment: My original intent was to translate the universal property argument to ideal language, but then I had thought I had stumbled upon something simpler.

Comment: Oh yes of course, it means that $u_i=0$, my bad. Regarding your response to the first point, I will play around with it some more, I still think there is something to be done here without making the assumption.